# dotnet build command fails while restoring packages

Tags: nuget, azure-devops, nuget-package-restore

I have a project that's building fine locally but the build in VSTS it fails in `dotnet build` command. The error looks very strange to me because I have no idea why a build command would try to restore packages again. Here's what the error looks like:

> 2018-07-09T11:06:48.2541705Z   Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for
>   source
>   'https://mycompany.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/5b9fd539-d653-4771-aa3c-6544d73b1234/nuget/v3/flat2/system.data.sqlclient/index.json'.
>   2018-07-09T11:06:48.2562315Z   Response status code does not indicate
>   success: 401 (Unauthorized).

Prior to build step, I have a dotnet restore step which is completed successfully. Restore step uses a NuGet.config file which includes private feeds in VSTS but the URLs do not look similar to the one in the error. Here's the file just to make it clear.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="MyCompany.NuGet.Internal" value="https://MyCompany.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/MyCompany.NuGet.Internal/nuget/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="MyCompany.NuGet.ThirdParty" value="https://MyCompany.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/MyCompany.Nuget.ThirdParty/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

What could be the problem here? Is dotnet build step ignoring the NuGet.config file completely and trying the feeds in the project? I have no idea how that feed URL is generated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by passing `--no-restore` argument to `dotnet build` command.

I just read [this article here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build?tabs=netcore2x#description) and wanted to give it a shot and it worked.

> With .NET Core 1.x SDK, you needed to explicitly run the dotnet
>   restore before running dotnet build. Starting with .NET Core 2.0 SDK,
>   dotnet restore runs implicitly when you run dotnet build. If you want
>   to disable implicit restore when running the build command, you can
>   pass the --no-restore option

It looks like `dotnet build` in VSTS does not care about the NuGet.config file and tries to do a restore without it.