# Failed to run dotnet restore

Tags: c#, .net, windows, nuget

When trying to run `dotnet restore` in the root folder of my project, I get a following error:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.100\NuGet.targets(676,5): error : Unable to obtain lock file access on 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch\lock' fo
r operations on 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config'. This may mean that a different user or administrator is holding this lock and that this pr
rashed and left an inaccessible lock file, in this case removing the file 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch\lock' will allow NuGet to continue. [ 
C:\Users\user\Documents\Kurs C#\FirstProject\FirstProject\FirstProject.csproj]
```

None of the solutions I've found in the Microsoft docs work. I've managed to find a possible solution here:
[Dotnet commands fail when restoring Nuget packages in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64552282/dotnet-commands-fail-when-restoring-nuget-packages-in-shell-script)
However, how exactly am I supposed to change these permissions?

Comment: Did you try removing the file it tells you to in the error?

Comment: this file does not exist, and it's not visible even if I change visibility settings for hidden folders and files

Comment: I know this sound stupid, but did you try restarting your computer?  File locks can be acquired in a myriad of ways and often they just... go away when you reboot.

Comment: This may help to find who is locking that file, after finding the guilty process you could terminate it and retry to dotnet restore (https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows)